# Index-Match Look-up search criteria error

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to use a Index-Match function to search my pivot table for the most current week. There is no issue when I type in the value as a string myself but I cannot reference a cell with that exact same value as the criteria for instance.

=Index(E:E, Match("3/7/2018 Total", A:A,0) this works as intended but I am attempting to automate this process.

Referencing a cell with =CONCATENATE(TEXT('Performance Summary'!B1,"m/dd/yyyy"), " Total") to create this same style in a cell does not work.

I have also attempted performing this function within the index-match function itself to no impact. Using a vlookup with this same function previously worked but ceased to function after a one time use (I suspect due to the fact that the table size changes daily, which messes it up even though i referenced the entire row range for the columns).

I am interested in any solution to solve this problem. Thanks.

Comment: Also you don't want dd you want only d on the format.

Answer (score 0):

You have one too many `d`s in the format.  Also you can skip using `Concatenate()`:

```
=INDEX(E:E,MATCH(TEXT('Performance Summary'!B1,"m/d/yyyy")&" Total",A:A,0))
```